# Arch Linux. AUR package mysql cannot be built with makepkg. ERROR: A failure occurred in build()

Tags: c++, mysql, linux

I tried to compile the package mysql from source. When I run `makepkg -s` inside the directory where `PKGBUILD` is located the building process fails and I have this output:

```
[ 89%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/mysqld.dir/main.cc.o
[ 90%] Linking CXX executable ../runtime_output_directory/mysqld

/home/natalya/Downloads/mysql/src/build/sql/sql_yacc.cc:2047: warning: type ‘yysymbol_kind_t’ violates the C++ One Definition Rule [-Wodr]
 2047 | enum yysymbol_kind_t
      | 
/home/natalya/Downloads/mysql/src/build/sql/sql_hints.yy.cc:252: note: an enum with different value name is defined in another translation unit
  252 | enum yysymbol_kind_t
      | 
/home/natalya/Downloads/mysql/src/mysql-8.0.20/sql/parser_yystype.h:239:7: warning: type ‘union YYSTYPE’ violates the C++ One Definition Rule [-Wodr]
  239 | union YYSTYPE {
      |       ^
/home/natalya/Downloads/mysql/src/mysql-8.0.20/storage/innobase/include/fts0pars.h:50: note: a different type is defined in another translation unit
   50 | typedef union YYSTYPE
      | 
/home/natalya/Downloads/mysql/src/mysql-8.0.20/sql/parser_yystype.h:240:17: note: the first difference of corresponding definitions is field ‘lexer’
  240 |   Lexer_yystype lexer;  // terminal values from the lexical scanner
      |                 ^
fts0pars.y:62: note: a field with different name is defined in another translation unit
lto-wrapper: fatal error: write: No space left on device
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld.gold: fatal error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [sql/CMakeFiles/mysqld.dir/build.make:168: runtime_output_directory/mysqld] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:8100: sql/CMakeFiles/mysqld.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:172: all] Error 2
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

Before building the package I upgraded all the packages on the system using pacman and I have the `base-devel` group installed.
Any idea what could cause this issue? How can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Seem like your hard drive is full or you're trying to write into a read only drive

Comment: But my hard drive is not full. How could it be?? Here's the output of df: 
/dev/sda6        53G   23G   28G  46% /
/dev/sda8       190G   53G  128G  30% /home
/dev/sda2       101M   78M   23M  78% /boot

I build all the packages in my home directory. How much disk space does this package need? I think I don't completely understand how building from source works in Arch Linux.

Comment: I'm in speculation area but how large is your /tmp directory? It would surprise me but I can imagine a build system using that path for some artifacts. Usually, /tmp is in a ramdisk about half the size of the main memory amount.

Comment: If I'm trying to write into a read only drive then how can I change it?

Comment: I don't think I have the answer to that. It would depend on which drive is read only, which type of filesystem, etc.

Comment: This is my /tmp directory:
tmpfs           1.9G  789M  1.1G  43% /tmp
Disk space available: 1.1GB

Comment: Do you think that 1.1GB of free space is not enough for building of the package? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: If the problem is about my /tmp directory then I should try to create new directory /tmp (in my /home) and then set the TMPDIR environment to this directory. Hope this will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. I created directory /tmp in my /home
`mkdir ~/tmp`
and then I set the TMPDIR environment to this directory:
`export TMPDIR=~/tmp`